# Technique of memorizing the Quran

Tags: halal-haram, quran

my name is Abdullah. I'm currently learning to memorize the Quran. I discovered an excellent method for memorizing the Quran verse by verse. It is a method in which you create "associations" for each word (letter or sound) in the Quran. First, I would create a route for memorizing all of the visual(objects) "associations," so that on the first point (for example, the entrance to my house), there is a Quran or a person pointing up in the air, and that is my "association" for Allah (Subhana wa ta'aala), and then when I remember that someone was pointing up in the air, I immediately know that I have to say, Allah. And, yes, I am aware that associating with Allah (Subhana wa ta'aala) is a shirk, but this is different; I am associating with the word or name "Allah," not with the actual Allah (Subhana wa ta'aala). Also, keep in mind that I don't just use this technique to memorize Allah (subhana wa ta'aala); I use it for all of the words, letters, and sounds in the Quran. Is this technique permissible in Islam?

Answer (score 1):

I can't say if your technique is haram or not. But I can teach you another technique which I find very helpful.

Go to Quran.com and find the surah you're trying to memorize. Go to the ayah you need to memorize and play the audio again and again. After listening to the audio a bunch of times, try to silently follow along with the audio, as far as you can (even if it's only the first letter of the ayah). Keep repeating and you'll see that you're able to follow along more and more until you're able to completely sync your recitation with the audio. The whole process takes like 10 minutes.

For example, let's say you're trying to memorize Surah Mulk, Ayah 1. So while you're playing the audio (on repeat) of the first ayah, you follow along like this:

Tabaara

Tabaara

Tabaara kalla zee

Tabaara kalla zee

Tabaara kalla zee biyadihil mulk

Tabaara kalla zee biyadihil mulk

.

.

.

..

...

After multiple attempts, Inshallah you can finally sync your lips with the audio and say

Tabaara kalla zee biyadihil mulk wa huwa 'alaa kulli shay 'in qadeer

Once you're able to do that, stop playing the audio and keep repeating what you just learned like 10 times. Then practice the ayah whenever you can every hour or so. You might forget after like 1 or 2 hours, but then you can just take a quick look at the ayah again and you will quickly remember it Inshallah. No need to repeat the audio again.

With this technique, I was able to easily memorize 1-2 ayahs per day (sometimes even 3 or 4). I used this technique to memorize Surah Mulk and the first 51 ayahs of Surah Yaseen (still ongoing) in a very short time.

May Allah help you.

Comment: Thank you very much For you answer. May Allah bless and you whole family, assalamualaykum.